# How to write such a regular expression to find 8 numbers in a line?

Tags: lua, regular-language

```
1   0   0   1.8 0   0   0   0   
0   0   2.44    0   0   0   1.241   0
```

like the data above

How can I write a regular expression in lua to find the 8 digital numbers (maybe int or float) in one line by using `String.match()`

BTW every number is split by a `'\t'`

Comment: If less than 8 numbers, ignore line? If more than 8 numbers, ignore only past the 8th number, or ignore the whole line as non matching? Or, are the lines guaranteed to always contain 8 numbers?  Anyway, you can match an int or float with something like `'%d-%.?%d+'`

Comment: one line is guaranteed to contain 8 numbers

Comment: `local n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8 = (loadstring or load)("return "..your_data:gsub("\t", ","))()`